# Local Git repository has multiple branches, while Github (remote) repository has only master

Tags: git, github

I am trying to commit changes to a branch named: **orders-page**.
This branch is in the local git repository. After commiting those changes I push them to the Github server. I cannot see them there - I can see only master.

This is how I push them to github:

```
git add .
git commit -m "description"
git push origin orders-page
```

This is what I get when I type:

```
git branch
#  choose-vehicle
#  f7-react-starter
#  geolocation
#  master
#  * orders-page
#  socket.io
```

This is the github branch list:

[image]

I have tried `git remote -v` and got this in return:

```
# origin    https://github.com/myuser/my-repo.git (fetch) // correct url
# origin    https://github.com/myuser/my-repo.git (push) // correct url
```

I have tried `git branch --remote` and get (in red):

```
origin/auth
  origin/choose-vehicle
  origin/f7-react-starter
  origin/geolocation
  origin/master
  origin/orders-page
  origin/socket.io
  origin/work-schedule
```

How to merge those branches to the Github repository?

Comment: How do you push the branch? Where do you look for the branch on github?

Comment: I push using: `git push origin branch-name`
I look for the branch on github in the Branches tab, next to the commits.

Comment: Does the push return any error? Do You see the changes you are trying to push on Github master branch ?

Comment: That should work fine. Are you sure you don't get any error? What is your github repo? What is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: @DominikWosiński no - there no errors. @JB Nizet the `git remote -v` returns with: origin https://github.com/myuser/my-repo.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/myuser/my-repo.git (push)

Comment: @Raz and do You see any changes on the master branch on Github after the `git push` ? EDIT: Ok, I  can see this in the post now.

Comment: @DominikWosiński No. I have also edited the question

Comment: Could You also try `git branch --remote` just to ensure that this is not the issue with the GitHub?

Comment: @DominikWosiński I did, edited the question again.

Comment: So, basically this means that the branch was pushed sucessfully and it is present on the GitHub remote repo. I'm not an expert with the GitHub itself, but maybe this is connected with some privacy settings for the repo ? Or maybe it's some issue with Github WebUI ?